# Project folder name in NetBeans interfering with JSF/GlassFish deployment

Tags: jsf, netbeans, glassfish

I am not sure if this is a JSF issue or a NetBeans issue. I am very new to both.  I am also not sure if stackoverflow is the best SE site for this, so if I am wrong please help me out and migrate it.  Thanks.

I have a project in a folder, let's say C:\Folder1, and when I try to "deploy" it on the GlassFish server, I get strange errors about a missing class... though that class is not even a part of this project.  I believe that C:\Folder1 may have been something I used in the past for a different project but that is long gone.  So this new project, if I move it to folder C:\Folder1a or C:\Folder2 or ANYTHING else but C:\Folder1... then it will deploy fine. But if I move it back to Folder1 (i.e. the exact same directory structure underneath that level), I get the mysterious error messages from GlassFish server about being unable to find the class that it doesn't even need.

I got a suggestion elsewhere to try "cleaning" and re-building the project, but that did not work. Here is more detail about the steps I followed.

Create new project in Netbeans, point it to an empty folder called Ex2605. After that, I bring a couple source files (.java and .xhtml) into that Ex2605 directory structure. When I clean and build, it says ok. When I try to deploy, I get this error:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LShoppingCart;. Please see server.log
>   for more details. C:\\Ex2605\nbproject\build-impl.xml:721: The
>   module has not been deployed. See the server log for details. BUILD
>   FAILED (total time: 16 seconds)

"ShoppingCart" is a class from a different project, that I once long ago had in a directory named Ex2605 at the same location. But that directory is long gone, it has been removed from the Netbeans project list, and there are NO references to the ShoppingCart class anywhere in any of the files currently in the Ex2605 folder. So that fact that Netbeans apparently is looking for something called LShoppingCart tells me it maintains a history somewhere else of what I used to have in the Ex2605 folder, and apparently I need to purge that history but have no idea how.

If I try all of the above with any directory NOT named Ex2605, it works fine.

Any ideas? Obviously I can work around it, but it still irks me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Netbeans has a compile cache that sometimes [causes problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965798/netbeans-deployment-fails-after-class-rename). You could delete the compile cache and see if it helps.

Here are the steps from the answer to my question:

1. Stop the server
2. Clean the project
3. Stop NetBeans
4. Delete %HOME%.netbeans\6.9\var\cache
5. Start NetBeans

Comment: Fantastic!  I asked this on 3 separate Netbeans/JSF forums and got no responses.  Rock on StackOverflow, rock on Matt Handy!  (the posted solution works, of course)